# ImageMagick convert error: /rangecheck in resolveR with PDFs larger than 600KB

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, thumbnails, ghostscript

When using this command on PDFs larger than about 600KB

```
<? passthru("convert -verbose -scale '200x200+0+0>' ".$pdf."[0] $image"); ?>
```

I get this error output:

```
ERROR: /rangecheck in resolveR
Operand stack:
   PageCount   4763294   47   46
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1   3   %oparray_pop   1   3   %oparray_pop   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1129/1686(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:107/200(L)--   --dict:107/200(L)--   --dict:104/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:241/347(ro)(G)--   --dict:16/24(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
```

Anyone have a workaround for these larger files?  I need to pull a page 1 thumbnail from some as large as 4 MB.

Per Kurt below I also tried accessing gs directly:

```
<?
    $image = "3.jpg";
    $pdf = '3/ABS_Survey_for_Load_Lines_CIB_100.pdf';
    if (!file_exists($image)) {
        echo passthru("gs \
-sOutputFile=$image \
-sDEVICE=jpeg \
-g200x200 \
-dPDFFitPage \
 $pdf");
    }
?>
```

This gives same error:

```
ESP Ghostscript 815.02 (2006-04-19)
Copyright (C) 2004 artofcode LLC, Benicia, CA.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
ERROR: /rangecheck in resolveR
Operand stack:
   PageCount   4763294   47   46
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1   3   %oparray_pop   1   3   %oparray_pop   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1122/1686(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:107/200(L)--   --dict:107/200(L)--   --dict:104/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:241/347(ro)(G)--   --dict:16/24(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad news!  I was playing with an online converter using a problem PDF and it gave a "bad pdf" error.  All of the PDFs will open in Acrobat mind you but- I took some of the problem ones and re-saved them using my Acrobat 9 and lo and behold the thumbnails got created no problem...

So the issue had to do with whatever software the shipyard used to make the PDFs.

Comment: To discover the PDF Creator and PDF Producer software, run: `pdfinfo my.pdf`. You can also use (a recent version of) Ghostscript to repair your defect PDFs: `gs -o out.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite in.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick's `convert` does not open and process PDF files itself. Instead it uses as a  *delegate* for PDF inputs Ghostscript.

The error you show is a typical Ghostscript error message.

To debug this, you should try first to run Ghostscript *directly* to see if it is *really* Ghostscript's fault:

```
gs \
  -dBATCH \
  -dNOPAUSE \
  -sOutputFile=200x200px-output.jpeg \
  -sDEVICE=jpeg \
  -g200x200 \
  -dPDFFitPage \
   2000-kilobyte-input.pdf
```

Also, look for the version of Ghostscript you have: `gs -v`. (You should use a recent version, for example 9.05)

---

**Update:**

Since your version of Ghostscript (ESPGS 8.15.2)...

- ...is more than 6 years old (at the time PDF-1.6 and Acrobat 7 were the newest versions for PDF),
- ...but since you very likely are processing even the most current PDF formats (PDF-1.7 and Acrobat X are current now),

...you are well advised to upgrade your Ghostscript (which has to consume such new files) to a current version too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm stuck for now with ESP Ghostscript 8.15.2.  I was getting "Unknown switch -o3.jpg - ignoring" but based on man page I changed -o to -sOutputFile=  at which point I am back to getting "ERROR: /rangecheck in resolveR"

Comment: @jerrygarciuh: OK, ESP Ghostscript 8.15.2 is rather old. (And it does not understand the newer `-o output.jpeg` syntax. I will update my answer above accordingly.

Comment: Your updated syntax still receives:  ERROR: /rangecheck in resolveR

Comment: @jerrygarciuh: Ok, we know 3 things now for sure: (1) The syntax is correct now for ESPGS 8.15.2 (no more *"Unknown switch..."*-error.  (2) The fault lies with your version of Ghostscript, not with ImageMagick. (3) You should definitely try the same command (maybe at first on another system, if the current one is difficult to upgrade) with a newer version of Ghostscript....

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice!  I will see what versions I have available on other servers.

Comment: Bad news!  I was playing with an online converter and it gave a "bad pdf" error.  All of the PDFs will open in Acrobat mind you but- I took some of the problem ones and re-saved them using my Acrobat 9 and lo and behold the thumbnails got created no problem...  Very sorry to have wasted your time.